# C# How do I export a MemoryStream's content to the console and write the stream's content onto the console?

Tags: c#, stream, console, streamwriter, memorystream

The title says pretty much all.

I am making a logging system using the "Debug" class (Debug.WriteLine, etc.), and I've attached a TextWriterTraceListener to it so it can log all the strings that has been written using Debug write functions.

e.g:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(stream);
TextWriterTraceListener writer = new TextWriterTraceListener(standardOutput);
Debug.Listeners.Add(writer);
Debug.WriteLine("123 test");
Console.WriteLine("Hi there!");
//*Here add the already existing data in the stream ('stream')*
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually created `MemoryStream` use [Console.Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out.aspx) which represents standard output stream:

```
TextWriterTraceListener writer = new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out);
Debug.Listeners.Add(writer);
```

Comment: The thing is, the console isn't always on. I call it using unmanaged functions, and if I write into the stream, it will open it. (or won't write in it, I'm not so sure)

Comment: @LouisTakePILLz I'd guess as alternative you can try using `ConsoleTraceListener` and after it was added write contents of your stream using `Debug.Write`.

Comment: How would that make me more able to import the content to the console? I can't link any stream to the console until it shows up.

Comment: @LouisTakePILLz Ok, maybe I did not understood your idea or difficulties but if you are creating console using `AllocConsole` function then after it was created you can add listener and then flush contents of the stream. I just googled a bit about `AllocConsole` and found relevant code on PInvoke http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.attachconsole. Is this close enough to your case?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to do. But the only problem is that I can't print anything in the console before I use "AllocConsole"; I would have to write the out data to another stream and then push the stream's content to the console. Is there any efficient and clean way to do this?

Comment: @LouisTakePILLz Yes, I think writing data to other stream and then pushing contents of the stream to console will work if log is not big and there is enough RAM. Generally it is better to persist log entries in file or database and after console started pull all new entries and push them to console. Another thing is that it looks like you are trying to reinvent parts of existing logging systems. For example there is `log4net MemoryAppender` which could be queried for log events programatically, see http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender.GetEvents.html.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I haven't been successful at getting this concept to work (To be honest, I haven't really had the time).